# Как правильно написать сокет между двумя компьютерами на Python?

Tags: python, сокет, ip

Как правильно написать сокет для двух компьютеров на Python. Я пробовал, но не приходило ничего на компьютеры. Может быть что-то с Ip-адресами. И как их найти правильно.

Comment: Вы не могли бы приложить Ваш код Вашей попытки к вопросу?

Comment: @Михаил Ребров Как добавить сюда код? Напишите.

Comment: @АлександрИванов, нажимаете "править" под вопросом, вставляете код, выделяете, жмете кнопку `{}` в редакторе.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простейший пример:

```
# Клиент, запрашивает страничку с web сервера,
# принимает ответ и печатает его

from socket import *
HOST = 'www.py4inf.com'
PORT = 80

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send('GET /code/romeo.txt HTTP/1.0\nHost:www.py4inf.com\n\n'.encode())
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()

print (data)
```

Comment: А можно сделать это не через web страницу, а через ip адреса компьютеров

Comment: Конечно. Так прямо и задайте в переменной *HOST*. И порт задайте > 1000, свой какой-нибудь. Только обратите внимание, что здесь идёт обращение к HTTP серверу. Поэтому запрос посылается вполне определённого формата. И ответ приходит, в соответствии с протоколом. Если "на другом конце" будет такая же программулька, то посылать и отправлять можно любые строки. Главное, что бы у такой сладкой парочки операции ввода и вывода были взаимодополнительны.

Comment: Но на принимающей стороне всё несколько сложнее... Там надо созданый сокет привязать к определённому порту (забиндить), потом объявитm его слушающим и после этого ждать входящего соединения. Только после этого можно будет использовать *read()*.